# What's the difference between "float" and "fractional" in Haskell?

Tags: class, haskell, types

```
Prelude> let c=[1.0,2.0]
Prelude> :t c
c :: Fractional t => [t]
```

I'd expect "c" to be a list of either Num or Float. Why Fractional? Is there any implicit type conversion going on here in Haskell?

Comment: Well the `.0` indicates a *fractional* part of the number (even if in this case is `0`). What would expect the type of `[1.5]` to be? It cannot be `Num` because if it were `Num` it would have to be convertible to, say, `Int` but there is no unique sensible way to do so (round to lower? round to higher? round to even? round to odd?). Also you don't want `1.0` to have type `Num` while `1.1` to have type `Fractional`... a slight typo could change way too many things in a program. Hence the simple rule in the report.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it happen:

```
> :set -XNumDecimals
> let c=[1.0,2.0]
> :t c
c :: Num t => [t]
```

The answer to "why `Fractional`" is basically "because the Report says so":

> ```
> float →   decimal . decimal [exponent]
>       |   decimal exponent
> ```
>
> A floating literal stands for an application of `fromRational` to a value of type `Rational` (that is, `Ratio Integer`). Given the typings:
>
> ```
> fromInteger  :: (Num a) => Integer -> a  
> fromRational :: (Fractional a) => Rational -> a
> ```
>
> integer and floating literals have the typings `(Num a) => a` and `(Fractional a) => a`, respectively.

I would guess the Report says so because it is a nice simple rule to explain: no dot/exponent, it's `Num`-polymorphic, yes dot/exponent, it's `Fractional`-polymorphic.

Two relevant bits are:
https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-190002.5
https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1

Comment: @Bakuriu: really? My GHC-7.10 does recognise it; `-XNumDecimals` is available since 7.8 actually.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Uh Now it does. Guess I made a typo when trying it the first time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit type conversion in Haskell. Numeric literals have polymorphic types.

```
> :t 3
3 :: Num a => a

> :t 3.5
3.5 :: Fractional a => a
```

Standard Haskell treats any number with a decimal point as fractional, even if the fractional digits are all 0. It also treats anything written in scientific notation as fractional. There's a GHC extension you can use to be more polymorphic with such representations if you like.

As for the question in your title, `Float` is a concrete type (`Float :: *`), while `Fractional` is a type class (`Fractional :: * -> Constraint`). You can write lots of functions that will work with all sorts of `Fractional` or `RealFrac` or `RealFloat` types without having to worry about the exact representation.

Side note: `Float` is a special-purpose type, for specialized algorithms, formats, etc., and certain cases where compact representation of arrays is more important than precision or numerical stability. When you want floating point, the one you usually want is `Double`.